# Print hangs to Dell AIO 926

Tags: drivers, usb, printing, dell, lexmark

I have a Dell AIO 926 with Xubuntu 14.04. A quick search reveals it is in fact a rebranded Lexmark x3650.

After adding the printer and messing around trying to get it to work, I am at a point where I cannot print: sending print jobs simply has them queue behind the earliest one which is hanging at "processing". Flushing the queue and printing again creates a new, hanging, print job.

Steps taken:

- The Lexmark installer for those are broken in Linux (does not accept authentication password) so I followed this:

  http://wiki.freegeek.org/index.php/Lexmark_Installer_Issues
- Added a printer using the `Settings` > `Printers` interface, selected the detected printer, selected Lexmark 3600-4600 series, printing a test page and monitoring for messages reveals:

  > A wrong printer was detected. All print jobs are cancelled.
- I tried debugging and getting more info following [Ubuntu wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingPrintingProblems)
- As far as I can see, it is recognized:

  ```
  $ lpinfo -v
  usb://Dell/Photo%20AIO%20Printer%20926?serial=6H0SF91&interface=1

  $ lsusb
  Bus 001 Device 004: ID 413c:5115 Dell Computer Corp. Photo AIO Printer 926

  $ ls -l /dev/usb/lp* /dev/bus/usb/*/*

  /dev/bus/usb/001/004
  [...]
  /dev/usb/lp0
  ```

  - with permissions `[ crw-rw-rw- 1 root lp ]` on both
  - `dmesg | grep lp` confirms the VID and PID (printer found unplugged/plugged during my testing)
- Searching on the error in question, I found [this page](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1243920.html) and followed the steps as closely as possible:

  It's for a different printer so in my case:

  - modified `lx36-46.pdd` and replaced the VID and PID respectively with `513c` and `5115`
  - modified `99-lexmark-08z.rules` and added a line with those details
  - modified `lxdx.conf` (since `lxdx` was referred to in the PDD) and replaced all instances of the VID and PID with the new values
- Then I removed the old printer and added it again this time specifying the PDD explicitly using CUPS interface at `localhost:631`

  Now printing a test page leaves the printer hanging perpetually at "Processing..."

So I guess I've overcome the "printer not recognized" problem but there's still an issue where the data seems to be not getting to the printer...

Can anybody give me any pointers as to where to go next? I'm getting a little desperate as to what I can do to resolve this... starting to think that Lexmark/Dell printers are a lost cause.... Didn't have this issue with HP and Brother printers in the past...

**EDIT**

Just sent a print job via CUPS web interface, received in `cups access_log`:

```
localhost - - [09/May/2014:12:22:32 +0100] "POST /printers/Dell_Photo_AIO_Printer_926hu HTTP/1.1" 200 404 Print-Job successful-ok
```